# Django with Jinja2 - using custom context processors

Tags: django, jinja2

I am using Jinja2 as my template system. I have created a jinja2.py file and set environment to use custom template filters, etc.  But i don't know how to set custom_processor via jinja2?

```
def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)

    env.filters['datetime'] = format_datetime

    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
        'thumbnail': thumbnail,
        'customimagecrop':customimagecrop,

    })
    return env
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Jinja2 backend does not support context processors. See [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24694) (warning - it's a long read). You could try django-jinja, which [does support context processors](http://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/#_context_processors_support).

Comment: Thank you i would use it for memcached but i have read that there is no need with jinja2. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by using a context processor for memcached.

Comment: I was doing the caching ( via memcached ) inside a custom context_processor... ( workCategories = cache.get(cache_key_workcategories) )

Comment: I'm not sure why the choice of template language should affect whether or not you use caching.

Comment: From the jinja2 docs --> Jinja2 uses a different loader API. Because the internal representation of templates changed there is no longer support for external caching systems such as memcached.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant - [those docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/switching/#api) are about switching from Jinja1 to Jinja2, and it's talking about caching templates, not caching template variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114233/discussion-between-ratata-and-alasdair).